# Optimize the query which currently uses sub-query

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
SELECT
  *
FROM notifications
WHERE id NOT IN (
  SELECT
    id
  FROM notifications sn
  WHERE
    sn.status = 'errored'
    AND sn.data->>'end_date' IS NULL
    AND reference IN (
      SELECT
        reference
      FROM notifications sn
      WHERE
        sn.data->>'end_date' IS NOT NULL
    )
)
```

- `id` is unique - it's a primary key.
- `reference` is an identifier and multiple notifications can have the same `reference`.
- notification can be in `errored` or other state.
- If notification contains `sn.data->>'end_date'` it means it's the cancelation notification.

The goal is to filter out errored notifications IF we already received cancelation notification for given `reference`.

My query works but it is very slow given that table is only ~200k rows and I think there's a more efficient way to achieve the same result.

Current query's `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, COSTS, VERBOSE, BUFFERS)`:

```
Seq Scan on public.notifications  (cost=24409.49..48382.49 rows=87160 width=903) (actual time=1647.547..1755.070 rows=174189 loops=1)
   Output: notifications.id, notifications.reference, notifications.created_at, notifications.updated_at, notifications.provider, notifications.status, notifi
cations.provider_customer_ref, notifications.raw_data, notifications.raw_json, notifications.product_offering, notifications.data, notifications.product_type
   Filter: (NOT (hashed SubPlan 1))
   Rows Removed by Filter: 95
   Buffers: shared hit=459591
   SubPlan 1
     ->  Nested Loop Semi Join  (cost=0.42..24409.49 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=5.261..1647.403 rows=95 loops=1)
           Output: sn.id
           Buffers: shared hit=437797
           ->  Seq Scan on public.notifications sn  (cost=0.00..24408.80 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=5.193..1640.764 rows=204 loops=1)
                 Output: sn.id, sn.reference
                 Filter: (((sn.data ->> 'end_date'::text) IS NULL) AND (sn.status = 'errored'::editor.notification_status))
                 Rows Removed by Filter: 174080
                 Buffers: shared hit=435722
           ->  Index Scan using notifications_reference on public.notifications sn_1  (cost=0.42..3.65 rows=2 width=28) (actual time=0.031..0.031 rows=0 loops=204)
                 Output: sn_1.reference
                 Index Cond: ((sn_1.reference)::text = (sn.reference)::text)
                 Filter: ((sn_1.data ->> 'end_date'::text) IS NOT NULL)
                 Rows Removed by Filter: 1
                 Buffers: shared hit=2075
 Planning:
   Buffers: shared hit=16
 Planning Time: 7.447 ms
 Execution Time: 1763.507 ms
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sample data would help a lot here.

Comment: You've already said "reference" is not  a primary or unique key.  But what about "id"?

Comment: @jjanes `id` is the primary key. About the "feel" - bad wording, I saw the query isn't instant given the relatively small table (~200k rows) and takes time in seconds, so I very likely do something very "expensive" and maybe it's unnecessary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the query plan, this is your problem:

> ```
>        ->  Seq Scan on public.notifications sn  (cost=0.00..24408.80 
>              rows=1 width=32) (actual time=5.193..1640.764
>                  rows=204 loops=1)
>              Output: sn.id, sn.reference
>              Filter: (((sn.data ->> 'end_date'::text) IS NULL) AND (sn.status = 'errored'::editor.notification_status))
>              Rows Removed by Filter: 174080
> ```

The databases removes 174080 records, to find 204 records. Create an index on the combination of these columns and it should be able to do an index scan, within a few milliseconds.

Comment: Beauty in simplicity. Thank you for this idea, with the index query runs in 35ms, which is good for me!

Answer (score 1):

There are two seq scans of the same table, one is fast and uses few buffer accesses, and the other is slow and uses many.  (The top seq scan in the plan inherits almost all of its time and all of its buffers access from its children, adding little to those values itself)

I think this indicates that the down-plan seq scan is needing to deTOAST the large sn.data column, and this takes all the time.

One idea is refactor the table so that end_date is stored in a real column, not embedded in a giant json.  But barring that, you can at least use a functional index to pull out the end_date and store it separately in an index.

```
create index on notfications ((data->>'end_date'), status);
```

This should avoid needing to deTOAST "data" all the time.  I think this is the same index Frank is suggesting, but the motivation is partially different.  Being able to jump directly to the NULL values is nice, but not having to deTOAST the "data" column would be enough of an improvement.

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive explanation (had to google the toast term). I won't be moving out the `end_date` in an own column for now, but index did indeed solve the issue - now query runs in under 35ms, so it's great. Appreciate your comment and answer!

Answer (score 0):

This should be easier to read and understand.  Whether it performs "better" is a different story:

```
with cancellations as (
  select reference
    from notifications 
   where sn.data->>'end_date' is not null
)
select *
  from notifications sn
       left join cancellations c on c.reference = sn.reference
 where not (    sn.status = 'errored'
            and sn.data->>'end_date' is null
            and c.reference is not null)
```

The antijoin expressed as a left join can be changed to either a `not in` (usually a bad idea because of nulls) or an `exists` correlated subquery.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I initially had 2 CTEs in the query which I eventually pushed into subquery. CTEs read easier but I believe adding an index (suggested in other answers) would really be a simple yet efficient piece to resolve the issue.